# Searching for multiple values at the same time

Tags: vba, excel

This code is now working to search multiple values in multiple sheets.

How can I search multiple values at the same time without having to write every one. For example, I want to put in column A all my search values, and then I click on search, and it should search and give the value for all of them at the same time. What should I change in the code to do this function?

Please see the code and the images.

```
'Definning variables
 Dim i, j, k, l, m, n, no_sheets As Integer
 Dim key, cursor, sheetname As String
 Dim flag As Boolean
 Dim sheet1_count, sheet1_row, row_count As Integer


     sheet1_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A:A"))

     no_sheets = 4 ' Number of sheets
     k = 2
     sheet1_row = sheet1_count 'My start in result sheet

     key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & sheet1_count) ' The value that the user will put in searching sheet in column A

     For i = 2 To no_sheets ' sheet2 then sheet3 then sheet4 then sheet5 ..etc
         flag = False
         sheetname = "Sheet" & i
         row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A:A")) ' It's a counter that will contain the range of row A in each sheet
     For j = 1 To row_count 'I'll start from row 1 until the last sheet
         cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & j) 'Searching in column A in each sheet (1st row - last row) and put the value in this variable
             If key = cursor Then ' If the entering value in sheet1 equal the value that we have in current sheet, do the following
             ' Copying the data
             flag = True ' The data found
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("B" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("C" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("D" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("E" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("F" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("G" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("G" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("H" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("H" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("I" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("J" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("J" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("K" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("K" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("L" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("L" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("M" & j)

                 sheet1_row = sheet1_row + 1
                Else

         End If
     Next j 'Go to the next row
Next i 'Go to the next sheet
  MsgBox "finished, Do another search..!"


            If key <> cursor Then
              flag = False  ' If the value not found

                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("G" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("H" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("J" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("K" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("L" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"

            End If



  End Sub

Sub MatchUnMatch_Click()
Dim i, j, k, l, m, n As Integer
Dim ListA_count, ListB_count, ListC_count, ListD_count, ListE_count As Integer
Dim key, cursor As String
Dim flag As Boolean

ListA_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnmatch").Range("A:A"))
ListB_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnmatch").Range("B:B"))
'ListA_count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
'MsgBox ListA_count & " " & ListB_count
'=======================================================================================================
'
'
' Matching Logic for List 'A' and List 'B'
'
'
'=======================================================================================================
k = 2
For i = 2 To ListA_count
    key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("A" & i)

    For j = 1 To ListB_count
        cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("B" & j)
        'MsgBox "Key=" & Key & " Cursor=" & cursor
        If key = cursor Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("C" & k) = key
            k = k + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'=======================================================================================================
'
'
' List 'A' items not in List 'B'
'
'
'=======================================================================================================
ListC_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnmatch").Range("C:C"))

k = 2
For i = 2 To ListA_count
    key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("A" & i)
    flag = False
    For j = 1 To ListC_count
        cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("C" & j)
        If key = cursor Then
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If flag = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("D" & k) = key
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

'=======================================================================================================
'
'
' List 'B' items not in List 'A'
'
'
'=======================================================================================================
k = 2

For i = 2 To ListB_count
    key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("B" & i)
    flag = False
    For j = 1 To ListC_count
        cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("C" & j)
        If key = cursor Then
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If flag = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("E" & k) = key
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[see the image pleas, to understand what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xck6.png)
I want to put in row A in search sheet (first sheet) many numbers and then I want to click on search bottun one time only that should give me all the values at the same time.I don't want to click one search more than one time.

Comment: why not just set up a multidimensional array?

Comment: What do u mean by that? I am new in this world . Explain if u can

Comment: You have asked [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506832/) before. You have deleted question once you got the answer. This is not fair. Not a single line from the above lines is your work. I suggest you to put some effort.

Answer (score 0):

a tipp first.

```
Dim i, j, k, l, m, n, no_sheets As Integer
Dim key, cursor, sheetname As String
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim sheet1_count, sheet1_row, row_count As Integer
```

Only the last variable will be an Integer. The others will be Variant. 
Sometimes this can be a problem.

I think you need to Dim an array/arraylist/collection/dictionary and then check if the the Value is in this collection. This should work.

Comment: Can u fix it to me according what you wrote ? please I need your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to search for a specific value in multiple sheets and copy the related row in result sheet using VBA Macro code

```
Sub Macro_Click()
Dim i, j, k, l, m, n, no_sheets As Integer
Dim key, cursor, sheetname As String
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim sheet1_row, row_count As Integer
no_sheets = 10
    k = 2
    sheet1_row = 2
    For i = 2 To no_sheets
        key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2")
        flag = False
        sheetname = "Sheet" & i

        row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A:A"))
        For j = 2 To row_count
            cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & j)
            If key = cursor Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & j)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("B" & j)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("C" & j)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("D" & j)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("E" & j)
                flag = True
                sheet1_row = sheet1_row + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

        If flag = False Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
        End If

End Sub
```